# Self-changing javascript characters in text editors

Tags: windows, javascript, virus

On Windows Server 2008-R2, certain javascript files are exhibiting the same behavior.  Text can be copied from other files and pasted into new ones.

In both NotePad++ and Windows' default notepad, characters in specific areas will either suddenly be hidden depending upon what's next to it or even switch order.

Is this a virus or some corruption that has been copied & pasted into other files or something else?

What is this?

Comment: What's the encoding of these JavaScript files? If it's UTF-8, you might have some unicode characters that are acting up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an encoding issue.

> If you use anything other than the most basic characters needed for English, people may not be able to read your text unless you say what character encoding you used.
>
> For example, you may intend the text to look like this:
>
> [image: proper encoding]
>
> but it may actually display like this:
>
> [image: improper encoding]
>
> Not only does inadequate encoding information spoil the readability of displayed text, but it may mean that your data cannot be found by a search, or reliably processed in a number of other ways.

Source: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding.en